# Pictures in my book

Tags: formatting, self-publishing, non-fiction, memoir, picture-books

I have recently been diagnosed with ALS. I was keeping a journal on the CaringBridge site, and I got enough feedback about it that I have decided to turn it into a book. I have added memories of my growing up. I’m curious if it is acceptable to add pictures about some of my memories. They are pictures of me, so legal is not an issue. I’m just not sure if it’s okay to add pictures in a book like this. Also, any recommendations for where to put the pictures? My first thought was to have a collage at the end of the book with pictures of some of the things I talked about. Or would it be better to put a picture at that spot in the book? Any input would be appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: I'm sorry to hear about your diagnosis. Can I suggest that you don't assume that acronyms are going to be meaningful to other people? For example, I didn't know what ALS stands for.

Comment: Thank you. Sorry.  I didn't even consider that.Amyotrophic lateral sclerosis (ALS), also known as motor neurone disease (MND) or Lou Gehrig's disease, is a disease that causes the death of neurons controlling voluntary muscles. Some also use the term motor neuron disease for a group of conditions of which ALS is the most common.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a publisher but I have read a whole, whole lot. So this is based on my observations.

Pictures tend to be full-page, and tend to be black-and-white with only a few exceptions.

Placement is usually one of the following:

1. The pictures are all in one place, usually in the middle of the book
2. There are pictures interspersed throughout the book, on pages next to the scene they are relevant to.

I am personally partial to #2. However I will also note that #2 seems to be done mostly only in children's books. I don't know why this is, as it seems much more practical to me to have the picture next to what it is describing.

At the end of the day though, this is something you would work with your publisher/editor on.